Loki Promtail pipeline template cant find variables
I have following issue with loki promtail. Here is one configuration snippet from my promtail:
        pipeline_stages:
          - cri: {}
          - regex:
              expression: '^(?P<time>.*?)\|(?P<level>.*?)\|(?P<process>.*?)\|(?P<logger>.*?)\|(?P<thread>.*?)\|(?P<client>.*?)\|(?P<user>.*?)\|(?P<message>(?s:.*))$'
          - labels:
              level:
              logger:
              thread:
              client:
              user:
          - labeldrop:
              - filename
          - template:
              source: testo2
              template: '{{ .level }} - {{ .user }}'
          - output:
              source: testo2


I'm using the regex function to receive the required information. After it I create the labels.
For the final message I would like to overwrite the output.
My example of the output message: INFO - testo
The problem occurs in the template function. The variables are empty. Normally I thought I can use from the regex/label value to parse the variable inside the template.
What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

to get the value from the label, the following format is required:
{{`{{ .level }}`}}


Try to use following content:
pipeline_stages:
  - cri: {}
  - regex:
      expression: '^(?P<time>.*?)\|(?P<level>.*?)\|(?P<process>.*?)\|(?P<logger>.*?)\|(?P<thread>.*?)\|(?P<client>.*?)\|(?P<user>.*?)\|(?P<message>(?s:.*))$'
  - labels:
      level:
      logger:
      thread:
      client:
      user:
  - template:
      source: message
      template: '{{ .level }} - {{ .user }}'

A few notes:

Seems you don't really need labeldrop as you don't have filename label
Make sure your regex is correct by using https://regex101.com/

